# Indian Solar dynasty king

Tags: history, suryavansh

Was there a Solar Dynasty king called Salisuka. If yes, please provide details of his place in the list of solar dynasty kings.

Comment: he was a king in Maurya dynasty and Maurya dynasty is believed to be related to Solar dynasty....